# Why isn't openmp parallel speeding up my randomForestSRC?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest

I'm using R's `randomForestSRC` library `Version: 2.2.0 Date: 2016-05-17`, which specifically says `The package runs in both serial and parallel (OpenMP)` in its description, and I'm sure it's loaded, as `sessionInfo()` says: `randomForestSRC_2.2.0`. I've followed the instructions for installing the openMP enabled version and downloaded it from [Ishwaran's site](http://www.ccs.miami.edu/~hishwaran/rfsrc.html).

Yet, I'm trying to speed up the building of a puny forest of 8 trees, and its not speeding at all :(

Serial:

```
options(rf.cores=1, mc.cores=1)
system.time(my.rfsrc <- rfsrc(Surv(score_years_before_label, status) ~ ., data = m, nsplit=10, ntree = 8, na.action = "na.impute", tree.err=TRUE, importance = TRUE))
user  system elapsed 
359.42    0.06  359.58
```

Parallel:

```
print(detectCores())
[1] 8
options(rf.cores=8, mc.cores=8)
system.time(my.rfsrc <- rfsrc(Surv(score_years_before_label, status) ~ ., data = m, nsplit=10, ntree = 8, na.action = "na.impute", tree.err=TRUE, importance = TRUE))
user  system elapsed 
378.07    0.05  314.67
```

I'm using `Windows 10 Pro`, 64-bit and my machine has 4 cores and 8 logical processors, and my data isn't that big:

```
print(nrow(m))
23070
print(ncol(m))
67
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you check using your operating system's monitoring tools on how many cores are actually being used in these two examples?

Comment: @Spacedman - I checked the task manager and in both cases it looks like all 8 processors are doing something, which takes ~15% of their time - none of them are working very hard and none of them are totally idle

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the package does support serial and OpenMP parallel processing.  However, the default CRAN build protocol and binaries do not enable this functionality out of the box.  Please see Page Two of the documentation, the section titled "OpenMP Parallel Processing – Installation", for additional details specific to your platform.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure I've followed the instructions - the package I'm using is the one from http://www.ccs.miami.edu/~hishwaran/rfsrc.html - it's randomForestSRC_2.2.0.zip with size 1.30 MB (1,365,819 bytes). Did I miss anything else?? (and thanks for the quick support! :)

Comment: The binary that is posted for Windows was built using Windows 8.1 Pro.  Unfortunately, we haven't tested it or built the package with Windows 10 yet.  The better way to go (always) on any platform is to compile the package from source using the posted directions.  A prerequisite is that the R Windows toolset be available on your system.  Compiling CRAN packages from source on Windows is a bit more complicated than other platforms.  I would look at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ for more information on how to do this.